# How to switch texture display quickly in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I use opengl in qt. I have several pictures with a size of 30000 * 20000, including single channel, three channel and four channel pictures. The function I want to achieve is to switch and display different pictures through the keyboard, and support moving and zooming. I have implemented this function now, but I encountered some problems.
I want to bind them to different texture units and switch them when painting. But it seems to have no effect.

```
void MyOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();        
    glGenVertexArrays(2, VAO);
    glGenVertexArrays(2, VBO);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    {
        if (!bindShaderProgram(m_shaderProgram, vertexSourceBG, fragmentSourceBG))
            return;
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vBGVertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), m_vBGVertices.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW);

        readImage();
        glGenTextures(IMAGE_NUM, texture);
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_NUM; i++) {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            int channel = m_vImage[m_imageIdx].channels();
            int internalFormat = GL_RGB, format = GL_RGB;
            getImageFormat(channel, internalFormat, format);
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, m_imageWidth, m_imageHeight, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_vImage[m_imageIdx].data);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
        }
        m_shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("aPos", GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5);//8
        m_shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("aPos");
        m_shaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer("aTexCoord", GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, 2, sizeof(GLfloat) * 5);
        m_shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("aTexCoord");
        m_shaderProgram.release();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
    }
}
```

```
void MyOpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f);  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);       
    {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);

        m_shaderProgram.bind();                    
        createCameraTransformMatrix();
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("model", m_mModel);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("view", m_mView);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("projection", m_mProjection);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+m_imageIdx); 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[m_imageIdx]);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("ourTexture", GL_TEXTURE0+m_imageIdx);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("imgWidth", m_imageWidth);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("imgHeight", m_imageHeight);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4);     
        m_shaderProgram.release();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[m_imageIdx]);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
    }
}
```

Switch the currently displayed texture by switching m_imageIdx. But no response.
I bound them to the same texture unit, and then loaded them when refreshing. Now they can be loaded, but the speed is too slow to accept.

```
void MyOpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);

        m_shaderProgram.bind();                    
        createCameraTransformMatrix();
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("model", m_mModel);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("view", m_mView);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("projection", m_mProjection);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[m_imageIdx]);
        updateImage();
        if (!m_vImage[m_imageIdx].empty()) {
            int channel = m_vImage[m_imageIdx].channels();
            int internalFormat = GL_RGB, format = GL_RGB;
            getImageFormat(channel, internalFormat, format);

            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, m_imageWidth, m_imageHeight, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_vImage[m_imageIdx].data);
        }
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("imgWidth", m_imageWidth);
        m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("imgHeight", m_imageHeight);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4);
        m_shaderProgram.release();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[m_imageIdx]);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
    }
```

I referred to some similar problems and tried `glTexSubImage2D`, but I needed to refresh the whole picture, so the efficiency was not improved.
I can't reduce the texture precision because the texture display needs high precision.
I hope someone can give me some advice.

Available code snippets.

```
//init
for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_NUM; i++) {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            int channel = m_vImage[m_imageIdx].channels();
            int internalFormat = GL_RGB, format = GL_RGB;
            getImageFormat(channel, internalFormat, format);
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, m_imageWidth, m_imageHeight, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_vImage[i].data);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
        }
```

```
//paintGL
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[m_imageIdx]);
m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("ourTexture", m_imageIdx);
m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("imgWidth", m_imageWidth);
m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("imgHeight", m_imageHeight);
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 4); 
m_shaderProgram.release();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[m_imageIdx]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not need to upload them every frame. What you did forget was to set the correct value for `sampler2D` uniform variable in the fragment shader (which you did not post).

`m_shaderProgram.setUniformValue("ourTexture", m_imageIdx);` must be called in the draw loop

- with correctly bound shader
- Do not use `GL_TEXTURE0` here, as pointed by @HolyBlackCat .
  By default, it uses data from `GL_TEXTURE0`. You can imagine `GL_TEXTURE` as an array of pointers to the actual textures. `glActiveTexture` sets which pointer is used for the subsequent GL calls and `glBindTexture` assigns to this active pointer.

The uniform sampler acts exactly the same, the index you assign to it is the array element it will work with.

This also means that you need to just bind all textures to separate units only once, e.g. how you do (needlessly) during initialization and then vary only the uniform sampler, no binds, not activates needing.

Comment: You don't need `GL_TEXTURE0+` in the uniform value, too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oops, you are correct, it should be just the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know what I did wrong. Switching idx can only display the first texture. The rest are black.

Comment: @jerx Okay, did you bind the texture to the same unit whose index you assigned to the uniform variable? Try rendering a single texture using GL_TEXTURE1 first, this will force you to set the correct values.

Comment: @Quimby  Thank you. It seems that  not supported ```GL_ TEXTURE0+idx```.

Comment: @jerx Yes, , uniform sampler should really just be `idx`.